# C - Passing pointer to byte

Tags: c, embedded

I am currently working on a USB protocol on an emb device. I must use the following function:

```
uint32_t USBDBulkPacketWrite(void *pvBulkDevice, uint8_t *pi8Data,
                uint32_t ui32Length, bool bLast)
```

My data is stored into an array. How do I pass that array to the function?
I tried calling the function:

```
USBDBulkPacketWrite(&g_sBulkDevice, &(g_pui8USBTxBuffer[0]), 512, 1);
```

But without any success. The problem is in the second argument. How can I get the address of the first element of the array?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The third argument is `512`. I can't see any problem with it.

Comment: Ok, edited to the second argument. But still, what is the *problem*?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, just edit it, it is the second parameter that cause problem

Comment: Like that...but what is the real problem?  What is the compiler error message?  What is the declaration of `g_pui8USBTxBuffer`?  Please read the [About] page soon, and note that problems related to "it doesn't work" need to provide enough information for people to be able to reproduce the problem for themselves.  An MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is a good idea.

Comment: There isn`t a compiler error, the USB protocol just don`t transfer data.

Comment: "But without any success" : what is that supposed to mean ? Does your program compile ? Does your device explode ?

Comment: Oh great. So how do you deduce that the problem is here?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ah; that's a different issue.  It suggests that there's something else wrong.  I'd lay odds that you need `g_sBulkDevice` and not `&g_sBulkDevice`, but we need a lot more code to be able to know that for sure.  Also, interfaces using `void *` make it hard for the compiler to help you avoid such problems.  You could pass any (non-const) address as the first argument to the function, with the compiler unable to help you spot the problems of passing the wrong type to the function.

Comment: I think about perhaps closing the question if no one see a problem in the function call.... Usb protocol are a couple thousand lines... So I will contact TI instead I think.

Comment: Close is probably a good idea.  Alternatively, show the code that declares the variables you reference, and also the code that makes the connection to the device (initializes `g_sBulkDevice`), and it would be helpful to provide a URL to the API you're using.  We don't know what it is, and who provided it.  Please do the reading suggested if you decide to ask again.  Make sure you provide the info we need to be able to help you.  Note that explaining what the problem actually is very important.  One other thing: you don't show the code checking the return value from the function.  You should!

Comment: Where does `USBDBulkPacketWrite()` come from?  Is there by any chance a maximum of 64 for `ui32Length`?

Comment: @Dmitry You are right. The OP is working with TI micro, so I guess it is stellaris or similar. So not more than 64 is allowed. Then the OP was initially right (not intentionally)  about the problem in the *third* parameter rather than the second.

Comment: There is a `USBDBulkPacketWrite()` function as part of the Stellaris USB Library... if that's the one you're using, it looks like the packets must be at most 64 bytes.  Also, `USBDBulkInit()` etc. should have returned a pointer to the device struct that you can pass in without the address-of operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between passing in &(g_pui8USBTxBuffer[0]) and just passing in g_pui8USBTxBuffer.  The addresses are the same.

The problem more than likely lies somewhere else in your code.  Please update your question with the all the other steps involved with creating the g_pui8USBTxBuffer.

Also, how are you sure that the issue is with the second parameter?  What debugging steps have you gone through?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `USBDBulkPacketWrite()` function as part of the Stellaris USB Library... if that's the one you're using, it looks like the packets must be at most 64 bytes. Also, `USBDBulkInit()` etc. should have returned a pointer to the device struct that you can pass in without the address-of operator.  This is mentioned in the documentation for the function in the API docs.

In fact, a look at the source for the function shows that it would simply return 0 without even attempting to send if you give it a packet size that's too large... so this is likely your issue.